# Is there anyway to assign custom property for html element in it's tag? Need pure html + js solution

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe this is weird, but this is what I need.
For example, we can do this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("some_id");

if ("asd" in elem)
    alert(elem.asd); // and this in second pass
else
    elem.asd = "dsa"; //this will be executed first
```

I want something like this:

```
<input type = "button" value = "test btn" asd = "something" />
```

But this does not work. maybe there is some other way?
I really can't use body.onload to assign needed things.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute is what you are looking for I guess.

Comment: sorry, but how it different from my example? I can't use any scripts to assign needed properties.

Comment: In my page a lot of stuffs load through `some_container.innerHTML = "some tags"`. Then global functions should be able to use custom properties of loaded elements. So, that properties must be already set.

Comment: Or maybe there, at least, some property like .net Control.Tag one, where I can store needed things, but assign it right in element tag?

Comment: try `elem.getAttribute('asd')` in if comdition. it should work

Comment: WHERE?! I telling I can't use scripts for that.

Comment: leave your HTML as it is, in if condition `elem.getAttribute('asd')` to get `asd` attribute of element

Comment: `var attr = elem.getAttribute("asd"); alert(attr);` that really works, but for unknown reason `elem.asd` is undefined. well, ok. Make it as answer, this is good one. Sorry, I confused your getAttribute with setAttribute of first commenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is good enough. But for accessing attribute you should say like bellow.

```
var attr = elem.getAttribute("asd");
alert(attr);
```

Comment: don't know who is minusing us and why. Don't think it was me. I added plus to you. Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin that property has been added in HTML itself. I'm just accessing it through JS

Comment: That's my point. You can't add made up stuff to HTML and have it still be HTML.

Comment: @Quentin SO you want to say it is not a valid HTML.

Comment: I'd rather you used valid HTML instead.

Comment: `asd` is not a valid attribute name. `data-asd` is (since HTML5).

Comment: @Quentin if you read "good enough" as "known to just fine" rather than "is good practice" or "is standards-compliant", this answer is technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create non-standard expando attributes. HTML 5 introduces [the `data-*` attribute set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) which is designed for adding custom data to HTML elements.

```
<input type="button" value="test btn" data-asd="something">
```

You can then access them through the `dataset` property.

```
var button = document.querySelector('input');
alert(button.dataset.asd);
```

If you want to support [old browsers](http://caniuse.com/dataset), you can use `getAttribute`:

```
var button = document.querySelector('input');
alert(button.getAttribute('data-asd'));
```

Or a library with a compatibility routine, such as jQuery:

```
var button = $('input');
alert(button.data('asd'));
```